# "dev/sda3: clean ..." message when I start the system

Tags: startup

Today I turned on my pc and this happened to me. Someone knows how to fix this?

[image: "/dev/sda3: clean..." message]

Comment: This is usually caused by something done in the last session  where you had a successful boot. Providing your release details, plus what you did that last session (esp. any installed packages/new sources used etc) would allow us to better help you.

Comment: I'll try the first link u send.

Comment: Last session i installed anbox but i rebooted more times and it has always worked, its the first time.